# Spring Restcontroller - Check if client disconnected

Tags: connection, spring-restcontroller

Is there a possibility to check in a Spring RestController, whether a client closed the connection?

I try to implement something like this:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Resource> createZipFile(@PathVariable String id) {

  // ...

  for (Task task : tasks) {
    boolean connectionBroken = // ???
      if (connectionBroken) {
        // exit!
      }
    // execute task which might take a bit time... 
  }

  // Return result...
}
```